# Get the label of an ObservableHQ radio button

Tags: observablehq

Is there a way to obtain the label of a radio button?

For example I have

```
viewof classification = radio({
  options: [
    { label: "Underweight", value: "Underweight" },
    { label: "Healthy Weight", value: "Normal" },
    { label: "Overweight", value: "Overweight" },
    { label: "Obese", value: "Obese" }
  ],
  value: "Underweight"
})
```

If I wanted to access the "Healthy Weight" label instead of the `classification` value of "Normal", is it possible?

Comment: in this case I'd recommend deriving the options from another data structure in a cell that can be referenced elsewhere that can also be used to map the values to the labels where necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the definition of the radio (i.e. this radio isn't being imported from a notebook you don't own), you could restructure this a bit to make that easier.

e.g. in one cell:

```js
options = new Map([
  ["Underweight", "Underweight"],
  ["Normal", "Healthy Weight"],
  ["Overweight", "Overweight"],
  ["Obese", "Obese"]
]);
```

and the radio cell:

```js
viewof classification = radio({
  options: [...options.entries()].map(([value, label]) => ({label, value})),
  value: "Underweight"
})
```

And in the cell you need to reference the label rather than the value:

```js
label = options.get(classification)
```

Comment: This is what I will do.  A tidy solution.